Sharp edges when merging vertices

When we merge vertices by distance, there's an option called sharp edges which creates sharp edges based on the custom normals data. I want to create a button using python, which when pressed, should merge vertices/ remove duplicate vertices and also enable the sharp edges option as well. I tried code, but almost all of them created sharp edges for all edges. Can you help me with the code?

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share the code you used which didn't work for you?

bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=self.merge_distance
mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
mesh.calc_normals_split()
split_normals = [Vector(ln.normal) for ln in mesh.loops]
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for edge in mesh.edges:
verts = edge.vertices
v1, v2 = verts[0], verts[1]
if split_normals[v1].dot(split_normals[v2]) < 0.99:
edge.select = True
bpy.ops.mesh.mark_sharp()

Thanks for the welcome McKenzie
